# Cropping out an image from an existing image

Tags: c++, python, opencv, image-processing

I would like to crop out an image from an existing image. I've taken an image and applied monochrome on it with threshold `98%` using imagemagick (is this doable in openCV?)

The resulting image is this:

[image]

Now from this Image I would like to crop out another image so that the final image looks like this:

[image]

**Question**
How can I do this in OpenCV? Note, the only reason I want to crop the image is so that I can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699181/131194) to get the part of the text. If there is no need to crop out a new image and instead just concentrate on black part of the image to begin with, that would be great.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to resize an image instead of crop it, is that correct?

Comment: @perfanoff birdy wants to crop it.  Stack Overflow is resizing the images.  [Before](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MKcXt.png). [After](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hMTnv.png).

Comment: @perfanoff that is correct. thanks for clarification. I am not trying to resize the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the text at the top and at the bottom are the regions that you want to [crop out,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13533305/176769) if they are always at the same location the solution is easy: **just set a ROI that ignores those areas**:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(argv[1]);
    if (img.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "!!! imread() failed to open target image" << std::endl;
        return -1;        
    }

    /* Set Region of Interest */

    int offset_x = 129;
    int offset_y = 129;

    cv::Rect roi;
    roi.x = offset_x;
    roi.y = offset_y;
    roi.width = img.size().width - (offset_x*2);
    roi.height = img.size().height - (offset_y*2);

    /* Crop the original image to the defined ROI */

    cv::Mat crop = img(roi);
    cv::imshow("crop", crop);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    cv::imwrite("noises_cropped.png", crop);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output image:**

[image]

If the position of the black rectangle, which is your area of interest, is not present on a fixed location then you might want to check out **another approach**: use the [rectangle detection technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8863060/176769):

[image]

On the output above, the area you are interested will be 2nd [largest rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13532779/176769) in the image.

**On a side note**, if you plan to isolate the text later, a simple **[cv::erode()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode)** could remove all the noises in that image so you are left with the *white box & text*. Another technique to remove noises is to use [`cv::medianBlur()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=medianblur#medianblur).You can also explore [`cv::morphologyEx()`](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html) to do that trick:

```
cv::Mat kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(7, 7), cv::Point(3, 3));
cv::morphologyEx(src, src, cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, kernel);
```

A proper solution might even be a combination of these 3. I've demonstrated a little bit of that on [Extract hand bones from X-ray image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15726091/176769).

Comment: The title will always be around the same location. Meaning it will always be on top of the image. How can I set the ROI that ignores the top? I'm new to opencv...is there a sample program that shows ignoring some ROI of the image based on color...

Comment: ok thanks. I tried the `morphologyEx` technique and got this image: http://imageshack.us/a/img16/5506/screenshot20130401at203.png now i guess i need to figure out the coordinates where the big rectangle starts...

Comment: The rectangle detection technique is exactly what I need since the rectangle location won't always be the same. I will use that answer to come up with a solution. thanks

Comment: Is there something that can be done in c++ to avoid typing `cv::` in front of all variables and rather just type `Mat Point ` etc.

Comment: Yes, after the `#include` section, add: `using namespace cv;`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution: scan lines from top down, bottom up, left-right and right-left. Terminate when the number of dark pixels in the line exceeds 50% of the total amount of pixels in the line. This will give you the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax coordinates to bound your cropping rectangle.